# Connect SSH command to stdout

Tags: ssh, rust

I am creating a command-line tool that dynamically finds a server from our cluster, then based on the cluster retrieves the appropriate private key held in an Amazon s3 bucket and copies it to a tempfile locally to connect to the server.

How would I SSH into an IP address and then allow the user to interact with the SSH session?

This example would open a ssh session to a machine in the cluster named "platform":

```
company_name ssh:platform
```

I've done this before in Ruby like so:

```
exec("ssh -i #{private_key_file.path} -R 52698:localhost:52698 core@#{platform_ip}")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at the [ssh2-rs](https://github.com/alexcrichton/ssh2-rs) crate; the docs have a good [example](http://alexcrichton.com/ssh2-rs/ssh2/index.html#run-a-command) of what you're trying to accomplish.

The gist of it is that you get a *channel_session* object, which has methods to read the outputs from the SSH console (copied from the docs here):

```
let mut channel = sess.channel_session().unwrap();
channel.exec("ls").unwrap();
let mut s = String::new();
channel.read_to_string(&mut s).unwrap();
```

Comment: The one you linked is a fork original is here: https://github.com/alexcrichton/ssh2-rs