# Unable to use std::process::Command - No such file or directory

Tags: rust

I am trying to use the following Rust code to connect to EC2 instances.

```
#[test]
fn client_ssh_timeout2() {
    match Command::new("/usr/bin/ssh -i /tmp/.ssh/25.pem ubuntu@ip").spawn() {
        Ok(_) => println!("Able to ssh"),
        Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
    };
}
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Error { repr: Os { code: 2, message: "No such file or directory" } }
```

Has anyone been able to use `std::process::Command` or any other Rust library to connect to EC2 instances using PEM files? I tried using ssh2-rs(libssh2) but couldn't connect to EC2 instances.

Comment: See also [Connect SSH command to stdout](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32641699/155423) and [TCP tunnel over SSH in Rust](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36865667/155423) for tangentially related questions.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks. Initially I started with ssh2-rs based on the above links but encountered issues with pem based authorization. So refactored the code to make of use std::process:Command

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This appears to be a misunderstanding of how to use `std::process:Command`. [`Command::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.new) takes **just** the program:

```rust
fn new<S: AsRef<OsStr>>(program: S) -> Command
```

[`Command::arg`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.arg) or [`Command::args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.args) are used to provide the arguments.

You will want something like

```rust
Command::new("/usr/bin/ssh")
    .args(&["-i", "/tmp/.ssh/25.pem", "ubuntu@ip"])
    .spawn()
```