# Command not found when using std::process::command in rust?

Tags: shell, rust, command-line-interface, std, mpv

So, i am getting this error when i run a command in linux terminal using std::process::Command.
The part of the code is:

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let mut playmusic = "mpv https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJQP7kiw5Fk";
    let status = Command::new(playmusic).status().expect("error status");    
}
```

The above code for the command, i found at rust [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.status). I tried everything in the docs, but none of them worked like using wait command.

Everytime i get this error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'error status: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', src/main.rs:46:63
```

Since, the error says that the command not found, i ran it in my terminal but there it ran successfully. But, when using this in std::process::Command, it fails.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to use std::process::Command - No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836973/unable-to-use-stdprocesscommand-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It fails, because you are using it wrong. You want to exec program `mpv` with argument `https://...`, but you are currently telling rust to run program `mpv https://...`, which of course does not exist. Too pass arguments to programs use `Command`'s method [arg](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.arg) or [args](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.args).

So your example can be fixed as such:

```rust
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJQP7kiw5Fk";
    let status = Command::new("mpv")
        .arg(url)
        .status()
        .expect("Failed to run mpv");    
}
```

If you want to know why it is designed this way, it's because rust will call one of the `exec` syscalls. See [exec(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) to understand how it works.