# Can't run an installed program using std::process::Command

Tags: rust, command-line-interface

I'm writing a small CLI app to set up my development environment based on a Jira ticket, currently I'm trying to open VS Code but I get a command not found error even though I can open VS Code from withing my terminal.

```rust
// jira.rs
use std::fmt;

pub struct JiraTicket {
    pub key: String,
    pub number: u32,
}

impl JiraTicket {
    pub fn new(key: String, number: u32) -> JiraTicket {
        JiraTicket { key, number }
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for JiraTicket {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}-{}", self.key, self.number)
    }
}

// command.rs
pub fn open_vscode(ticket: Option<&JiraTicket>) {
    let path = match ticket {
        Some(path) => path.to_string(),
        None => ".".to_string(),
    };
    let vscode_command = Command::new("code")
        .arg(path)
        .status()
        .expect("An error ocurred while opening vs code");
    if vscode_command.success() {
        println!("{}", "Opened VSCode".green());
    } else {
        println!("{}", "Failed to open VSCode".red());
    }
}
```

I already looked at:

- [Command not found when using std::process::command in rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74002429/command-not-found-when-using-stdprocesscommand-in-rust)
- [Unable to use std::process::Command - No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836973/unable-to-use-stdprocesscommand-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: you need to add `.arg("/C")` as the first arg to launch it with cmd.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is true on Windows, but maybe you can skip "cmd" altogether

Comment: I received an error when using just "\C" suggesting me to use r"\C", though I still got the same error

Comment: Yeah, I updated the code, I was using "cmd" just to see what could solve it. I updated the code to reflect it's current status

Comment: `Command` not found, `.green()` and `.red()` do not exist. Please provide a proper [MRE]. Not even a `main` exists ... how do you expect us to reproduce your problem if your code is not executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"code.cmd"` seems to work:

```rust
let vscode_command = Command::new("code.cmd")
        .arg(path)
        .status()
        .expect("An error ocurred while opening vs code");
```

I'm not sure why `"code.cmd"` works but `"code"` doesn't, though.

Might be related to [rust-lang issue #37519](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37519).

Comment: I see! I also tried "code.exe" never though of using .cmd that's very interesting.

Comment: I found out by typing `where code` to see where `code` actually comes from